# Track how many times an event occurs over a period of time

Tags: python, benchmarking

I'm working on a small RPG project in Python, and I have a couple of variables I need to track rates for.
One is a damage over time thing - if a target receives X amount of damage over the past y seconds (possibly as long as 10 minutes for some of the bigger enemies) they get stunned.  (Thus, more skillful players who can actually dish out more damage get stun bonuses...at higher risk of being stunned, since its turn based and the enemy also gets more attacks in the same period)

I envision this as comparing (Health-10-minutes-ago -- Health-now) to the stun threshold for the enemy in question after each attack.  The only problem is, I have no clue how to track what a variable was in the past.

The other is tracking a few variables I want to scroll up/down at a specified rate, in the background.  (I'd just have it check on how long the variable has been dropping the next time I use it (and zeroing it if the sum is negative), but I need to trigger a different method as soon as one of these variables hits zero.  And I'd prefer to have higher data resolution than just changing the value by x every minute on the minute.

If there's a devtool around that's freely available that would help handle this sort of thing, even if it's not for Python, just point it out to me.  Python is pretty graceful about allowing non-Python, and if I need to swap over completely, I should be able to manage.  (Well, assuming it's still capable of handling objects...procedural programming for a project with as many little bits as this would require a *major* rework of the entire program structure...and would still end up being a barely intelligible morass as far as my OOP-brainwashed mind is concerned.)

Comment: What about creating an object of a new type, behaving as a variable, but internally storing history of values/rates/statistics?

Answer (score 0):

First possible solution what I have figured was something like this:

```py
# On these timestamps you have gained these demages:
hits_hostory = {1385723418: 2, 1385723420: 20, 1385723425: 15, 1385723428: 3}

# Current timestamp
now = 1385723429

# Calculate hits in last 10 seconds
hits_sum_moving_10 = 0
for t, h in hits_hostory.iteritems():
  if t > now - 10:
    hits_sum_moving_10 += h

print "In last 10s you got %s demage" % hits_sum_moving_average_10
```

But there might be some better Python type which could help more. Also you have to solve cleanup of the `hits_history` dict as it would only grow - IMO it should be easy to backup only items going through "if" condition and then replacing whole `hits_history` by this new smaller one.

Side note: for nice video on games programming in python see http://youtu.be/duc3jYgAaR0